# How to enable creating campaigns?

Tags: administration, campaign

Despite being administrator for our Salesforce instance, I am not able to create campaigns. I ticked all boxes in my personal settings, but still I can see neither button nor element in the dropdown list...

How to solve that problem?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be a Marketing User in order to create campaigns.

From the documentation:

> **Marketing User**    When enabled, the user can create, edit, and delete
>   campaigns, configure advanced campaign setup, import leads, and update
>   campaign history via the member import wizards. Available in
>   Professional, Enterprise, and Unlimited Editions.
>
> To use the campaign import wizards, Marketing Users must also have the
>   Marketing User profile (or the “Import Leads” permission and the
>   “Edit” permission on campaigns in Enterprise and Unlimited Edition
>   organizations).
>
> If this option isn’t selected, the user can only view campaigns and
>   advanced campaign setup, edit the Campaign History for a single lead
>   or contact, and run campaign reports.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was as easy as this. I tried that before but it did not save my settings properly...

Answer (score 2):

By "personal settings" you mean "Marketing User" etc permissions on your user record?

1. In the Profile is the Campaign tab set to "Tab Hidden" by any chance? Can you add it to your tabs (under the plus icon) - I think that's what determines content of "Create new" menu.
2. What happens when you force navigate to new Campaign url? it's `eu1.salesforce.com/701/e` (use your instance)
3. Go to Setup -> Campaigns -> Search Layouts and examine the "List views" entry. Did somebody hide the button?

Comment: Acutally, it was easier than that. It only did not save my settings properly...

Comment: Oh, the countless times it boils down to "user error" :D Happens to the best of us!